# bxSlider: Slider inside slider, disable parent touch event if child slider is target

Tags: jquery, nested, bxslider

I'm trying to setup a bxslider inside another bxslider. The problem I have is that I want to prevent the touch event on the parent slider when the child slider is the event target. Here is what it looks like:

ui.js:

```
contentslider = $('.contentslider').bxslider({
        startSlide: 1,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        infiniteLoop: false
}); // Parent slider

itemslider = $('.itemslider').bxslider({
        startSlide: 0,
        pager: true,
        controls: true,
        infiniteLoop: false
}); // Child slider
```

index.html:

```
<ul class="contenslider"> <!-- Parent slider-->
   <li>Slide1</li>
   <li> 
       Slide 2
       <ul class="itemslider> <!-- Child slider -->
           <li>Slide 1</li> <li>...</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

bxSlider has the "touchEnabled" option but I don't think I can disable it on the fly?

Thank you in advance.